# HTML/CSS layout issue

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have to make a page with a responsive design and it doesn't really work out for me.

This is how the layout should look like (the black blocks are going to be images):
[image: Grid lay-out as it should be]

The problem is making it responsive. On smaller screens, the shape of the layout should be the same, but has to fit the screen no matter what the size of the screen is. On wide screens, this is what the layout becomes:
[image: Grid lay-out why it's not good]

I've tried several things, but the problem keeps occurring and it's not because of one line of CSS or anything, but I just don't understand how to fix the core of this problem.

Can anyone make a Fiddle to solve this, just with black boxes?

---

Ok, so here I have the progress. The problem is the margins. All the blocks should be 5px away from each other. When I do that, it goes wrong. Now, I have all the blocks with the right size, but I only need them to be separated 5px.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <img class="mainImg" src="http://www.calvijn.nl/media/3529/IMG-      20130925-WA0001_500x500.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <img class="subImg" src="http://stage.elephantcs.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/img-impression-5.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <img class="subImg" src="http://stage.elephantcs.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/img-impression-5.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <img class="subImg" src="http://stage.elephantcs.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/img-impression-5.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="link">
        <img class="subImg" src="http://stage.elephantcs.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/img-impression-5.jpg" alt="test" />
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
position: absolute;
left: 5%;
right: 5%;
top: 100px;
width: 90%;
height: auto;
background: red;
}

.mainImg {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 33%;
}

.subImg {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 33%;
}
```

Here's a fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4a6B/)

So, how can I pull the blocks apart?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I've tried several things"'_. Please post what you've tried, if for no other reason than so we don't duplicate the work you already did that didn't work.

Comment: I'm going to try it out again and I'll let you guys know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm9ZE/3/) / Watch [Fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm9ZE/3/show/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inner">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div><br/>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body,#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0px;
}
.inner{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.inner:nth-child(1){
    width:30%;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:5px;
}
.inner:nth-child(2){
    width:70%;
}
.inner div{
    display:inline-block;
    border-left:3px solid white;
    border-top:3px solid white;
    background-color:black;
}
.inner:nth-child(1) div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-top:3px;
}
.inner:nth-child(2) div{
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
```

---

### [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4a6B/2/)

Comment: It looks better, but I already had something like this, but the bottom of the big square image and the bottom of the other are different. I know, I look at every pixel a little too much, but I'm a designer. Thanks for your code though, I'll check it out and modify it to make it perfect :)

Comment: It looks different because of the border given to `.subImg`. You can give a better look by vertically centering the `.mainImg` relative to the `.subImg` by giving margin-top to it.I just updated my fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You should apply `min-height` to solve this issue.

An example here : http://jsfiddle.net/vRPfq/1/

But this will have impact to your images ofcourse.